# recursive (doall) in clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I have some structures with nested lazy sequences which read from files. When I'm testing I would like to be able to wrap them in a recursive version of doall to make sure all the data is pulled from the files *before* the files get closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defn doall-recur [s]
  (if (seq? s)
    (doall (map doall-recur
                s))
    s))

(use 'clojure.contrib.duck-streams)
(with-open [r1 (reader "test1.txt")
            r2 (reader "test2.txt")]
  (doall-recur (list (line-seq r2) (line-seq r1))))
```

Output:

```
(("This is test2.txt" "") ("This is test1.txt" ""))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(defn doall* [s] (dorun (tree-seq seq? seq s)) s)
```

Comment: Should we assume `s` needs to be a quoted version of the code to which `doall*` will apply?

Comment: No. Why di you think so?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in a unit test

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(postwalk identity nested-lazy-thing)
```